# Regex to return some characters but not one specific character

Tags: regex

The text is a list of words followed by data, e.g.:

```
Jakarta #header

Jakarta, formerly named Sunda Kelapa, Jayakarta and Batavia, the capital and the most populous city of Indonesia.
Juneau, capital of Alaska, population 32.660.
[sometext]
```

I need the entry starting with a word and ending with a fullstop followed by newline. I have a regex for that. The problem is the header on top of the page which contains some of the words for easier reference in the printed version. So **I need the word to be followed by a space or a comma, but not a newline.**

This doesn't seem to work:

```
\nJakarta[\s\,^\n].*\.(?=\n|$) #note this part: [\s\,^\n]
```

Is it possible to make such conditions for the character following the selected word?

Comment: maybe replace this part `[\s\,^\n]` with a `\S` ?

Comment: If it's followed by a space or comma, you don't need to say "not a newline", since a newline isn't a space or comma.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`^` only has special meaning when it's the *first* character after `[`. Otherwise, it just matches itself literally, it doesn't specify exclusions to previous matches.

If you want to match space or comma, use `[ ,]`. Since this doesn't use `\s`, it doesn't match other kinds of whitespace, so newline isn't included.